# How to trigger print in new window which is opened using RegisterClientScriptBlock in CS file

Tags: c#, asp.net, scriptmanager, registerclientscriptblock

This is my code to open it in new window, which works fine .

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "ViewDocument", "window.open('PdfViewer.aspx?fileName=" + displayFName + "  '  ,'_newtab');", true);
```

This above method opens and triggers print POP up window in IE, but not in Chrome. 
Should I be adding anything more to work in chrome? Please help me out here. Thanks.

Comment: window.open does not trigger a print.  The PdfViewer page may be doing that onload?  You used to be able to open/print/close, but Chrome changed the way it's print dialog is displayed and it would fail to print.  I would just create the link with a _blank target.  That'll open the print page in a new tab. (no need to use window.open there)  Then set "onload=print()" for that page.  The user will have to click the Print button to print the page and close the tab manually.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this script manager, when I am trying print it pops up current page. For some reason I cannot achieve both. Can you please help with example. Thanks.

Comment: if it's the current page, you can just use onclick="print()"